# MongoDB Realm returning a null app.currentUser after login - TypeScript React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mongodb, realm

I am creating a mobile app using MongoDB Realm and React. My user email/password signup is successful, and I am trying to add Custom User Data to the accounts in the registration process.

As of right now, my register function looks like this:

```
async function register(app: any, userDetails: any) {
  try {
    await app.emailPasswordAuth!.registerUser(
        userDetails.email,
        userDetails.password,
    ).then(() => login(app, userDetails.email, userDetails.password).then(
        (user) => {
            console.log(user);
            console.log(app.currentUser);
        }));
  } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
  }
}
```

And the login function:

```
async function login(app: any, email: string, password: string) {
  try {
      return await app.logIn!(
          Realm.Credentials.emailPassword(email, password),
      );
  } catch (err) {
      console.error("Failed to log in", err);
  }
}
```

The functions successfully resolve, and the first console.log returns the user object. However, attempting to log the app.currentUser returns null.

The login works fine, if I log the currentUser on any internal pages it returns fine, it just seems that it is not waiting for Realm to catch up before proceeding.

What can I do to ensure that app.currentUser is not null before continuing?

Comment: Interesting question. Perhaps it has something to do with the function call `register(app: any` and then reading `app.currentUser` at that point? e.g. perhaps app is not updated until the end of that function? Just guessing...

Comment: Good idea. Ill see if I can refresh the app variable. Thanks for your input